# Jenkins multibranch pipeline discover new branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

In Jenkins how can I discover new branches without triggering a build? I have setup the Jenkins integration with GitLab but I only want to trigger builds manually for my multibranch pipeline. When I turn off the push build trigger event in the GitLab this helps me trigger builds manually but new branches are no longer shown on jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins actually has an in-built option that allows you to do this. By default, when you select "scan repository", the new branches get identified and builds start on all of them. If you only want to identify the new branches without running builds on them, go to the configure page of the repo/organization in Jenkins. You should find an option "Automatic branch project triggering" which has a dropdown called 'Suppression strategy". There are three options:

- Don't suppress anything (builds will always run for any reason)
- Suppress indexing (builds will not run when you run "scan repository", but will run when triggered by webhooks)
- Suppress webhooks (builds will not run due to web hooks, but will be triggered when you run "scan repository").

Select the one you need.